# AlarmManager - get next scheduled time of an repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm setting a repeating alarm with `alarmManager.setRepeating(...);` and I now want to find out, what the next scheduled time of this alarm is.

How can I do that?

I can get the `PendingIntent` from the `AlarmManager`, but I don't know, how to find out, when the alarm manager will fire it's next event for my Intent...

**Question:**

*Is it possible (and if yes, how) to get the next time of an scheduled alarm?*

PS: I'm not asking for simple maths, I CAN calculate it on my own, I'm just curious, if I can get the information from somewhere else...

Comment: Please tell us in detail what you want exactly.

Comment: I think you have to calculate it by your own using the 2nd and 3rd argument of setRepeating. It is not hard to do that.

Comment: I hope, the question is more clear now... Although, @Aksiom, I think what you say is correct, I'm just not sure...

Comment: As far as the documentation of the AlarmManager and PendingIntent goes I do not see any way to just retrieve the information you are looking for. But maybe I am wrong. I hope you will find what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example

```
public static int mailSyncInterval = 10; // in minute

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MailSyncReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LoginActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, 1000 * 60 * mailSyncInterval, sender);
```

Receiver will call after every 10 min from current time in device.

**To get Next Schedule time**

MailSyncReceiver.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     long nextTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * mailSyncInterval);
}
```

Comment: Does this give the next scheduled time?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia, why 1000 * 60? and how do you pass the interval from another class?